# Node formatting automata library tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following piece of code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [state] (A)                {A};
    \node [state] (B) [right = of A] {B};

    \path[->] (A)  edge [bend left]  node [above]  {r} (B)
              (B)  edge [bend left]  node [below]  {r} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And what I get is this graph

[image]

which is quite close to what I would like to achive.

Now, I would like to get rid of the big circles as nodes, and instead plotting little points as nodes and the letters near the points.
How can I obtain this graph?

(For reference this is closer to what I'd like to get)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of placing the names inside the nodes, you could add labels next to them:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\tikzset{state/.style={circle,fill=black,inner sep=1.5pt,outer sep=4pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=-2mm]
    \node [state,label=180:A] (A) {};
    \node [state,label=0:B] (B) [right = of A] {};

    \path[->] (A)  edge [bend left]  node [above]  {r} (B)
              (B)  edge [bend left]  node [below]  {r} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update: I didn't realize that you wanted to have the small filled circles as well. This is now included using `$\bullet$`.

You can change the color of the circle and of the text individually. E.g., making the circle white and the text black:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [state, color=white, text=black] (A)                {A $\bullet$};
        \node [state, color=white, text=black] (B) [right = of A] {$\bullet$ B};
        
        \path[->] (A)  edge [bend left]  node [above]  {r} (B)
        (B)  edge [bend left]  node [below]  {r} (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives the following result:

[image]

A short cut if all nodes should be formatted like this is to give these options to the whole itkzpicture, e.g., `\begin{tikzpicture}[every state/.style={color=white, text=black}]`. If giving the colors is not an option then you can simple say `draw=none`, e.g.,
`\begin{tikzpicture}[every state/.style={draw=none}]`.

I hope that works for you.